# Carrierwave s3 403 (Forbidden) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm trying to get `carrierwave` to work with Amazon S3 (in my Rails 4 app), I use `fog` gem to upload the images to `s3`.

I'm currently successfully able to upload the files to my bucket. But I cannot get the images back. server is giving `403 (Forbidden)` error

However if I check the image, it's there uploaded in S3. My image path would be something like

```
https://<bucket name>.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/image/picture/8/card_34676_l.jpg&Signature=<signature>&Expires=<expires>
```

Following is my `carrierwave` config

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => '<key>',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => '<access key>',
  }
  config.fog_directory  = '<bucket name>' 
  config.fog_public     = false  
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>"max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"} # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

and I have setup the default grantee permission to `everyone` with

- list
- upload/delete
- view permissions

and have a default `CORS Configuration` setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

What could be missing?

Comment: Hey, sorry to hear you are having trouble. Just a couple questions to clarify. In what way are you trying to access them? ie via the url or by using the internal carrierwave functionality? If it is the url, how are you generating it?

Comment: Hey @geemus, thanks for the comment, actually it turns out to be a mistake from my side ;) My bucket didnt have a `bucket policy`, adding a policy with read access for the content fixed the issue. thanks again and keep up the good work on `fog` :)

Comment: Glad to hear you found the fix and thanks for taking time to update with the details!